# NetSuite Advanced PDF Template - Freemarker syntax

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I have a custom body field custbody_deposit_number that may have 2 values separated by a comma. I need to understand the syntax of the freemarker ?split built in. This is what the freemarker site says about ?split:

```
<#list "someMOOtestMOOtext"?split("MOO") as x>
- ${x}
</#list>
```

Prints

- some
- test
- text

can anyone provide help on how to implement my field in the ?split syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<#list custbody_deposit_number?split(',') as x>
  - ${x}
</#list>
```

You may also want to remove space around the commas, either via `${x?trim}` or using `?split(r'\s*,\s*', 'r')`

Comment: My current code looks like this: <td align="center">${record.custbody_deposit_numbers}</td>  This returns one value correctly. But sometimes I have multiple values in this field. I tried to use your #list code from above like this: <td align="center">
                  <#list ${record.custbody_deposit_number}?split(',') as x> - ${x} </#list></td>  I am receiving a parsing error - I must be doing something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `${...}` inside `<#list ...>`. See my earlier example.

Answer (score 0):

this is how we finally solved this issue:

```
<#if record.custbody_deposit_numbers?has_content>
    <#list record.custbody_deposit_numbers?string?split(",") as x>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">${x}</td>
        <td align="center">
            <#assign depositdate = record.custbody_deposit_dates?string?split(",")[x_index]>
            ${depositdate}
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <#assign depositAmt = record.custbody_deposit_amount?string?split(",")[x_index]>
            <#assign depositAmt1 = depositAmt?number>
            ${depositAmt1?string.currency}
        </td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```